# How do I redirect all existing links if I change Wordpress Multisite URL?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, seo, yoast

I have a Multisite that is currently set up as www.domain.com/en-US/ with a lot of pages set up already. I would like to change the multisite to www.domain.com/us. How should I do it? Since it is a site with more than 200 pages by now, would like to make sure the redirects are done properly.

I also have Yoast SEO Premium subscription if that helps. I am still pretty new to htaccess and writing redirect, so some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yoast does this automatically but to be sure go to "Rediret", select "301 moved permanently", use "bulk actions" to select the pages of your choice and click "apply".